# NSScanner Equivalent in C or Python

Tags: python, objective-c, c

I'm experienced with Objective C and easily know how to use NSScanner. I have a project I need to write in either C or Python that needs to use similar functionality to NSScanner(such as scanUpToString). Are there any standard or non-standard libraries that could provide similar functionality?

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the function you've mentioned or quote inline what its doing?

Comment: The NSScanner function "scanUpToString". I want to tell the program to scan up to a certain string and save that into a separate string

Comment: In plain old C, the functions to look at are `strtok`, `strstr`, and `strchr`. Looking at the man page for `strtok` there's a whole list of related functions that could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python take a look at the `find` method of `str`.

You could combine it like so:

```
foo ="barbazzapp" 
foo[:foo.find("zapp")] # Returns 'barbaz'
```